# How to install Intel PRO/1000 PT in Windows 10 1607?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, drivers, vlan

I tried installing drivers for this card in Windows 10 1607 but get the popup saying the following:

`Cannot install drivers. No Intel(R) Adapters are present in this computer.`

So if I cannot install regular drivers to get VLAN working how to do it with so called `inbox` drivers in Windows 10 1607? Support for VLAN in Windows 10 is a total mess. I heard a fix has arrived in build 14986?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to gain the ability to configure a VLAN? If so, it might help to edit your question to make that the focus vs. how to install the Intel drivers...

Comment: @Twisty Actually either or. Ultimate goal is VLAN but both topics are related.

Comment: Understood, but here at Super User you're more likely to get an answer if you ask a single question that can be answered with a single answer. Feel free to post two questions if necessary, but for the driver question avoid asking for a software recommendation (e.g. where to get an alternate driver) as such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Your using drivers that specifically supports Windows 10?

Comment: I have the same issue in 2020 with windows 10 2004. "No Intel(R) Adapters are present in this computer", when device manager clearly shows 2x Intel NICs installed